# WPF DropShadowEffect - Unexpected Color Difference

Tags: wpf, colors

I have a TextBlock with a DropShadowEffect.  Certain shadow colors are showing darker than the color specified, almost as though they are tinted.  However, this does not happen with every color.  Does anyone know why, or a way to correct it?

Here's a very basic example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="THIS IS TEXT WITH A SHADOW" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <!-- Expected Result -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFF0000">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="20" Color="#FFFF0000" />
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>

    <!-- Unexpected Result -->
    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF005E20">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="20" Color="#FF005E20" />
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>

</StackPanel>
```

Perhaps it has something to do with primary colors??

Comment: I don't have an explanation for this one, but I did take a screenshot of the result of this, and even the first case the drop shadow has a different color. I couldn't draw an correlations between how the two differ, but I wonder if the `DropShadowEffect` is altering the luminosity of the color. My tools are not advanced enough to look into this (I can only see RGB & HSV color spaces).

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting... perhaps there is something else going on here.

Comment: Yeah, and unfortunately, we can't use reflector to examine this code. Unless there is a magic version of reflector that can get the HLSL code for the shader effects.

Comment: I ran your code through Kaxaml and didn't notice anything unusual. Can you point exactly what you're facing?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22835703/1552016)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere it is converting the DropShadowEffect into a specific Sc value.

The closer to 1 you are, the less the difference (hence FF/255/1 works absolutely fine)

From looking into this and researching about on ScRGB, the gamma value of ScRGB is around 2.2. Therefore when converting from RGB to ScRGB, you may need to divide by 255, then nth(2.2) root of the value to come up with the final value.

E.g.

```
value 5E is 94

94 / 255 = 0.36862745098039215686274509803922

2.2root of 94/255 = 0.635322735100355

0.635322735100355 * 255 = A2
```

Therefore when you set the ScG of the foreground to 5E, you need to set the DropShadowEffect to A2.

This is just my observation and what i came up with from my research.

Why did MS implement it like this? I HAVE NO IDEA

Sources:

- [RGB/XYZ Matrices](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html)
- [Wikipedia sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB)

Comment: let MS do the conversion calculation back as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813934/273743