# WPF How to set desired color for Shadow?

Tags: wpf

This is sample code to draw ellipse, with shadow enabled. I set both Fill and shadow color as same. But in view shadow color is different. This may be WPF feature but in my scenario i want to set desired shadow color for the object.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">   

    <Grid>
      <Canvas>
            <Ellipse  Width="200" Height="300" Fill="#7D00FE">
                <Ellipse.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect   
                      ShadowDepth="5" 
                      Color="#7D00FE"/>                    
                </Ellipse.Effect>                
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It seems like a problem in the DropShadowEffect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130968/wpf-dropshadoweffect-unexpected-color-difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like that DropShadowEffect somehow affects the Color when it renders itself. This problem seems to be non-existing for primary colors (so named Colors, like Red, Blue, Aqua, etc. - but you don't have to use the name, you can specify them through #AARRGGBB format as well.)

I could not figure out the exact modification it does, nor can I offer a workaround (except to use named colors...), but I thought maybe it's worth noting it in an answer.

See this other questions, which probably point to the same "bug" or undocumented feature of DropShadowEffect:

- [DropShadowEffect with DynamicResource as color has weak
  visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736923/dropshadoweffect-with-dynamicresource-as-color-has-weak-visibility)
- [WPF DropShadowEffect - Unexpected Color Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130968/wpf-dropshadoweffect-unexpected-color-difference)

Update:
So, this is cheating, but for your specific question, it might solve the issue:

```
<Grid>
  <Canvas>
        <Ellipse  Width="200" Height="300" Fill="#7D00FE">
            <Ellipse.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect
                  ShadowDepth="5" 
                  Color="#BA00FE"/>                    
            </Ellipse.Effect>                
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

With a little invested work, one might be able to come up with a converter, that can convert a Color to an other Color, which will be the desired DropShadowEffect Color for the given Color. If I will have a little time I will come back to this.

My intuition suggests that the problem might be in the shader code for that particular effect, and that the output might differ on different hardware (and/or driver version), but currently I can not prove this.

**Update:**

I was wrong about named colors, it does not work for all of those, e.g.: Green is flawed, but the problem is not - solely - dependent on the green component of the Color. Intriguing.

**Update 2:**

So here is the converter I talked about earlier:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyCustomConverters
{
    public class ColorToShadowColorConverter: IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Only touch the shadow color if it's a solid color, do not mess up other fancy effects
            if (value is SolidColorBrush)
            {
                Color color = ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;
                var r = Transform(color.R);
                var g = Transform(color.G);
                var b = Transform(color.B);

                // return with Color and not SolidColorBrush, otherwise it will not work
                // This means that most likely the Color -> SolidBrushColor conversion does the RBG -> sRBG conversion somewhere...
                return Color.FromArgb(color.A, r, g, b); 
            }

            return value;
        }

        private byte Transform(byte source)
        {
            // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB
            return (byte)(Math.Pow(source / 255d, 1 / 2.2d) * 255);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("ColorToShadowColorConverter is a OneWay converter.");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here is how it should be used:

Resources part:

```
<namespaceDefinedByXmlnsProperty:ColorToShadowColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
```

Real usage:

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="100" Fill="#7D00FE">
    <Ellipse.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="50" 
                          Color="{Binding Fill, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Ellipse}}, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
    </Ellipse.Effect>
</Ellipse>
```

Thanks for Michal Ciechan for his answer, as it guided me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere it is converting the DropShadowEffect into a specific Sc value.

The closer to 1 you are, the less the difference (hence FF/255/1 works absolutely fine) because nth root of 1 is 1

From looking into this and researching about on ScRGB, the gamma value of ScRGB is around 2.2. Therefore when converting from RGB to ScRGB, you may need to divide by 255, then nth(2.2) root of the value to come up with the final value.

E.g.

```
value 5E is 94

94 / 255 = 0.36862745098039215686274509803922

2.2root of 94/255 = 0.635322735100355

0.635322735100355 * 255 = ~162 = A2
```

Therefore when you set the Green of the foreground to 5E, you need to set the DropShadowEffect to A2.

This is just my observation and what i came up with from my research.

Why did MS implement it like this? I HAVE NO IDEA

Sources:

- [RGB/XYZ Matrices](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html)
- [Wikipedia sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB)

Therefore in your example to have the same colour you need to use #B800FE

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Ciechan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839422/273743)(thanks to Mr Ciechan), Microsoft converts the DropShadowEffect into a specific Sc value.

So how to solve it?

Just let Microsoft do the calculation back by entering the RGB value into sRGB.

```
//Where the variable color is the expected color.
Color newColor = new Color();
newColor.ScR = color.R;
newColor.ScG = color.G;
newColor.ScB = color.B;
//the converted color value is in newColor.R, newColor.G, newColor.B
```

Refer to **Update 2** in [@qqbenq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835703/273743), for technical details for the binding converter(thanks to @qqbenq).

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    // Only touch the shadow color if it's a solid color, do not mess up other fancy effects
    if (value is SolidColorBrush)
    {
        Color color = ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;
        //Where the variable color is the expected color.
        Color newColor = new Color();
        newColor.ScR = (float)color.R / 255;
        newColor.ScG = (float)color.G / 255;
        newColor.ScB = (float)color.B / 255;

        return newColor;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula improved for [@qqbenq 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835703/273743).

The changes are in the Transform function. It is much more accurate and the difference is around 1 value.
Therefore in questioner example to have the same colour you need to use #BA00FF and you will get #7D00FF (questioner requested for #7D00FE).

Source of reference for the formula found in https://www.nayuki.io/page/srgb-transform-library

```
        private byte Transform(byte source)
        {
            // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB
            return (byte)(Math.Pow(source / 255d, 1 / 2.2d) * 255);
            double x = (double)source / 255;
            if (x <= 0)
                return 0;
            else if (x >= 1)
                return 1;
            else if (x < 0.0031308f)
                return (byte)(x * 12.92f * 255);
            else
                return (byte)((Math.Pow(x, 1 / 2.4) * 1.055 - 0.055) * 255);
        }
```